# Is it possible to increment a value with F in a json field in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

Is it possible to increment a value with F in a json field in django?

I have an object that contains a json field and I have some keys in it.

Is it possible to increment the key value inside a json used F?

Thank you for all.

```
credits = Company.objects.filter().first()
credits.meta_data = F('meta_data')['credits'] + 1
credits.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `F` is, but given you `meta_data` is a valid `JSON` object, you can manipulate it with `json` library, for instance:

```py
a = json.loads("{\"a\":1}")
#or a = json.loads(credits.meta_data)
print(a)
a["a"] = a["a"]+1
print(a)

{'a': 1}
{'a': 2}
```

You want to be careful (handle exceptions and ensure you save valid json content into this field), because even when you are using postgresql-specific json field, it does not guarantee that you are getting a properly formatted `json` objects from it.

Comment: It will not solve race conditions problem. The main goal of using F() + 1 in Django is avoiding a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the following code, since `F()` won't do the trick:

```
class IncrementValue(Func):
    """A class to represent the SQL function `jsonb_set` that increments a value in a JSONB field."""

    function = 'jsonb_set'
    template = """%(function)s(COALESCE(%(expressions)s, '{}'), 
        '{%(keyname)s}', 
        (COALESCE(%(expressions)s->>'%(keyname)s','0')::int + 1)::text::jsonb)"""
    arity = 1

    def __init__(
            self, expression: str, keyname: str, **extra,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            expression,
            keyname=keyname,
            **extra,
        )
```

And then use it like this:

```
assert (settings.DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] != 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'This method is not supported on SQLite')
   MyClass.objects.filter(id=myobjectid).update(myfield=IncrementValue('myfield', myjsonnestedkey))
```